# quay.io build frequently hits Docker Hub rate limit

Tags: docker, quay.io

I have a Dockerfile whose base is a public image on Docker Hub. In my quay.io triggered builds, I frequently encounter Docker Hub's rate limit error:

```
Could not pull base image: API error (500): toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
```

How to resolve this? Is it possible to specify a Docker Hub login on quay.io?

Answer (score 2):

There is no good solution for you at the moment. Quay.io doesn't support authenticated docker builds at this time (though we are looking to add this feature https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PROJQUAY-1299). The other route is that the owner of the DockerHub repos you pull from applies for an OSS account but that's likely not in your control.

A more immediate resolution is to host all your image dependencies on quay.io as well to be fully independent. What base images are you building from? Maybe it's already available in quay.io as well?

Comment: Another option is to migrate the builds to another platform that allows adding registry credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The one I'm using is the Python image: https://hub.docker.com/_/python Not sure what the policy about these official Docker image is...